# About amazon free tier instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am trying to use the amazon free tier instance. I got the free fedora server running. I installed a web server in there as well. Now how can I access that server from outside. What domain name to use. I don't have my own domain name now. Doesn't amazon itself give me something to access it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon EC2 assigns a default public DNS to each instance you spin up. Be warned, its not a user friendly name. To view your public DNS:

1. Login to the Amazon EC2 service and access your console
2. Click the gear icon in the top right hand corner, this will display a 'Show/Hide Columns' dialog.
3. Under 'EC2 Instance Attributes' select `Public DNS`.
4. Click Apply to close dialog and save options
5. Your public DNS now shows up under a column of the same name, copy the value from this column and fire away.

Note that to do anything useful with your instance (as far as accessing it remotely), that you should have enabled one or more [security groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html) for it.

[image]